# Rails: jquery autocomplete in a search form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm trying to implement `jquery autocomplete` in a search, but the autocomplete dropdown suggestion doesn't appear.

This is the basic search I have inside the `item.rb`:

```
def self.search(term)
  return where("0=1") if term !~ /\w{4}/
  where("lower(title) LIKE lower(:term)", term: "%#{term}%")
end
```

and inside the `application.html.erb` I have `<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>`

Now this is the setup I have regarding the autocomplete.... I have a sass bootstrap setup on my app and this is what I have done thus far:

Installed the `gem 'jquery-ui-sass-rails'`.

Added `//= require jquery.ui.all` in my `application.js` file.

Added the following jQuery inside the `items.cooffee` file

```
jQuery ->
  $('#search').autocomplete
    source: "/search_suggestions"
```

Created the controller and model:

```
rails g resource search_suggestion term popularity:integer
rails db:migrate

class SearchSuggestionsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    render json: SearchSuggestion.terms_for(params[:term])
  end
end

class SearchSuggestion < ApplicationRecord

  def self.terms_for(prefix)
    suggestions = where("term like ?", "#{prefix}_%")
    suggestions.order("popularity desc").limit(10).pluck(:term)
  end

  def self.index_items
    Item.find_each do |item|
      index_term(item.title)
      item.title.split.each { |t| index_term(t) }
      index_term(item.category)
    end
  end

  def self.index_term(term)
    where(term: term.to_s.downcase.gsub(/\s+/, '')).first_or_initialize.tap do |suggestion|
      suggestion.increment! :popularity
    end
  end
end
```

created and tested the following rake task

search_suggestions.rake

```
namespace :search_suggestions do
  desc "Generate search suggestions from items"
  task :index => :environment do
    SearchSuggestion.index_items
  end
end
```

and finally the search form looks like this:

```
<%= form_tag items_path, method: :get do %>
   <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], autofocus: true, placeholder: 'Enter keyword', data: {autocomplete_source: items_path} , :class=> "search-query search_size" %>
      <%= submit_tag 'Search', :style => "display: none;" %>
```

Any ideas what I might be missing here?

**Update 1**

I changed the gem to `gem 'jquery-ui-rails'`

and have this inside the `application.js` file:

```
//= require rails-ujs
//= require jquery-ui/widgets/autocomplete
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require_tree
```

and if I load the page and inspect the source the jQuery's are loaded it seems, so I have no idea what wrong!!

```
<script src="/assets/rails-ujs.self-817d9a8cb641f7125060cb18fefada3f35339170767c4e003105f92d4c204e39.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/version.self-c8e3d1203da26ea7efdf83c1eabb3f0ba55cb68e463f5ccf0d77bd15ce6a8e61.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/keycode.self-ad63cd20acf49dd333bbbc537454d7d475bd610eb5b88de0dca009f0c3d314b1.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/position.self-1b49c8c521e67a4a88bfdad6b4d944d33686d25009a0e40a1e170acdd7b6962a.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/safe-active-element.self-a1f1a1a7dae3269ce03f6fffb2dcc9b4a7490f5d546c65d54417bec3be24b668.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/unique-id.self-66e85ac85cd0b6b8b1bb89369fc65f608f716869dc0930862a8d421a57a9580a.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/widget.self-fca20bcec06d192f97cffa6e734e24360e227237b8ae7d7e7e60754df7d5444f.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/widgets/menu.self-0730fe713007bd93e6db569352a20ed92448299505ff6f525bc0dc6dd488254e.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/widgets/autocomplete.self-6a89d7a43741ec810ef95de143a7c0297e2e4368ebecff64493ebb7a9ac3a524.js?body=1"></script
```

Comment: are you using turbolinks? do you have an error message? otherwise could you give us some information about your tests, like is `$('#search').autocomplete` called? if yes tell us about that, otherwise are you retrieving the search suggestions from `/search_suggestions`? if not, how does your `rake routes` looks like and could you tell us: 1) where are the search suggestions generated? 2) how do you retrieve them? It is not clear to me what `source: "/search_suggestions"` is doing? a get request?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @ Fabrizio Bertoglio.. I have been trying to solve this for a while now. To answer your questions: No I'm not using turbolinks.  It seems like the  `$('#search').autocomplete ` is not been called. The routes are: `resources :search_suggestions` and basically this what I followed to implements this http://railscasts.com/episodes/399-autocomplete-search-terms?view=asciicast

Comment: I don't use `jquery-ui-sass-rails` but `jquery-ui-rails` gem. Fact is that gem would often not work and not load those assets, so I ended up importing my `jquery-ui` assets manually from http://api.jqueryui.com/1.11/ 
My question is, 1) do you have the jquery-ui assets in your page? `Inspect` your page and go on `sources`  to see that. 
Your autocomplete function depends on the following js file https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/0477890e2ccf93f3aaf5ca324ff7489381b35681/ui/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js

Comment: and the following and https://github.com/jhilden/jquery-ui-sass-rails/blob/master/jquery-ui-rails/stylesheets/jquery.ui.autocomplete.css.erb
Then control that you do not have error messages in your browser console

Comment: Thanks for the info @Fabrizio Bertoglio.. I updated my question with more info , feel  free to take a look at the info!

Comment: autocomplete has both js and css file, this is not the reason why your js is not executing. maybe you want to set a breakpoint inside this file https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/0477890e2ccf93f3aaf5ca324ff7489381b35681/ui/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js and see if that file is called?

Comment: @Fabrizio Bertoglio....  after inspecting the source inside the browser I found out this error: `can't find variable  $('#search').autocomplete({`...... hmmmm any ideas why this is happening, sorry kind of new to jquery and javascript in general.

Comment: @Thepap I don't see your `$('#search')` div. Do you have an `html` tag with `id: 'search'` ?

Comment: @Thepap so did you solve this?

Comment: Nope! still trying! I have manually installed the `jQuery-ui` and 0 errors pop up in my browser source inspector, but still nothing! I can't even render the local `json` array that is mentioned here http://railscasts.com/episodes/399-autocomplete-search-terms?view=asciicast .... any ideas why this happening? Or maybe a pointer on how I could solve this would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This is the form `erb` code

```
<%= form_tag products_path, method: :get do %> 
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], size: 30 %> 
<%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil %>
```

for this element

[image]

Inspect that element with your developer tolls and check the id generated from the `erb` code `<%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], size: 30 %>`

This is just an example, I don't have your app. On chrome you simply use the shortcut `CTRL + SHIFT + c` and then click with the mouse on the element you want to inspect (in this case that input form)

The developer toolbar pops up already selecting that div, you can also do right click and then inspect, with the mouse

[image]

I believe `text_field_tag :search` should have `id: 'search'`, but you are getting error in the console about the variable.

Test this on your chrome developer toolbar console `$('#search')` and see if it return an error or the `Javascript` object associated to the `<input id='search'>`

Maybe there is another reason. You are wondering if this is connected to `jquery-ui`, then check if you have the jquery-ui assets in the asset pipeline in the sources of your chrome developer tools

[image]

Or go in your console, test the [jquery-ui effect](http://api.jqueryui.com/effect/) in your page

```
$( "div" ).effect( "bounce", "slow" );
```

Debug this,

**first.** find out if you can trigger a breakpoint in this code

```
$('#search').autocomplete
```

**second.** test if you can trigger a breakpoint in this code

```
class SearchSuggestionsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    binding.pry
    render json: %w[foo bar]
  end
end
```

Also you need to understand that to achieve this, your app is using `AJAX` asynchronous request, so that your page without refreshing calls the server and gets the response `json: %w[foo bar]` with the element to display in the search suggestions

This is why you are calling `source: "/search_suggestions"` in your `jquery-ui` effect, because that is where you `client`/`jquery` is expecting to retrieve the `search` results

Jquery will hit your server at the url `source: "/search_suggestions"` and your server will return `foo bar` in json format, without reloading the webbrowser, jquery will display it

This is explained well on the [ruby on rails documentation](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#server-side-concerns) and in several videos

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I0crKwijP0Q

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FBxVN7U1Qsk

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fEYx8dQr_cQ&t=4s

I could keep writing and write you the code to fix quickly your problem, the reality is that you will never become auto-sufficient if you do not do the required training and understand the concepts and architecture behind this functionality

*AJAX* is supercool and I really wish you to enjoy those vides

Good luck
Bye
Fabrizio

Comment: Thanks for the help and pointers @Fabrizio Bertoglio... Right now I'm working on something else, but I'll let u know what happens when I implement your pointers!